# Do devices plugged into an unmanaged switch need to be on the same net?

Tags: networking, ip, switch

I have two USRP radios plugged into an unmanaged switch. Their IP addresses are 192.168.10.2 and 192.168.20.2 . If I connect these to the unmanaged switch and connect the switch to an ethernet port on a crystal workstation, do I need to reconfigure the ip addresses of the radios? If I do, how should I set them up?

Comment: Lucas, there are some important bits missing here: what are the two subnet masks for the two radios, and what are the IP details of the workstation? Also - what is a _crystal_ workstation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielK The two subnet masks are 255.255.255.0 . The workstation is same subnet mask and operating on 192.168.10.1 . Crystal is just the brand of workstation/pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the radios on separate subnets, you can add a second IP address to the workstation on the 192.168.20.x net and be able to talk to both.  If they don't mind being on the same subnet, then you can change the radio IP.

Comment: so if I change the IP of the radios to be 192.168.10.2 and 10.3 operating on the 10.1 for the workstation, I should be fine?

Comment: Should be good.

Answer (score 2):

For devices on different networks to communicate, you need a router.  So in this case, your workstation will not be able to communicate with one of your radios.

The simplest solution is to put all your devices on the same subnet, 192.168.10.0/24.